# Is there a method to create a Sympy equation solving system that recognizes the type of equation as well

Tags: python, swift, sympy, equation, equation-solving

I am making an equation solver using sympy. I plan the UI to be a single input field. However, I am not sure that how to make the system recognize the type of equation, lets say simulataneous, diffrential etc. Can anyone guide on this? Thanks

I am currently making this equation solver using Sympy which is essentially a python library. Cna anyone also guide how to implement this python code on my XCode swift app